# What is the use of agentmain method in java instrumentation

Tags: profiling, bytecode, instrumentation, javaagents

I done some java bytecode instrumentation with **-javaagent** argument and **premain** method. But this is the first time i hear about **agentmain** method. I have some questions about this method. Here follows it.

Both premain and agentmain method have same use?
When agentmain method invoked?
What is the use of agentmain method in java instrumentation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394646/#19400008 shows a sample application which starts an agent in a running JVM through the attach API. In this example it starts the JMX agent if it is not already running. So its `agentmain` method would be invoked then. This can be adapted to other agents. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html explains the meaning of `premain` and `agentmain`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`premain` is invoked when an agent is started *before* the application.  Agents invoked using `premain` are specified with the **-javaagent** switch.

`agentmain` is invoked when an agent is started *after* the application is already running.  Agents started with `agentmain` can be attached programatically using the Sun tools API (for Sun/Oracle JVMs only -- the method for introducing dynamic agents is implementation-dependent).

An agent can have both a `premain` and an `agentmain`, but only one of the two will be called in a particular JVM invocation.  In other words, your agent will either start with `premain` or `agentmain`, but not both.

You can find more information about this in the answer to the question [Starting a Java agent after program start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277219/starting-a-java-agent-after-program-start).