# How to use AspectJ Load-Time Weaving with Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to use AspectJ Load-Time Weaving to be able to intercept static methods. I followed [this example](https://github.com/spring-by-example/spring-by-example/tree/master/core/aspectj-load-time-weaving). When I execute the following test, the static method is well intercepted. However when I run directly the main class it is not intercepted.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28082632/1941316), I tested if the required agents are well loaded through `isAspectJAgentLoaded()`. Result: it's well loaded in both cases.

The configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:load-time-weaver />

</beans>
```

The Aspect class:

```java
@Aspect
public class PerformanceAdvice {

    @Before("execution(* org.springbyexample.aspectjLoadTimeWeaving.MyStaticClass.myStaticClass(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("*** hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }

}
```

The META-INF/aop.xml file:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <include within="org.springbyexample.aspectjLoadTimeWeaving.*" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="org.springbyexample.aspectjLoadTimeWeaving.PerformanceAdvice" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

The main class:

```java
public class ProcessorRunner { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context.xml", ProcessorRunner.class);
        if (isAspectJAgentLoaded()) System.out.println("*** AspectJ Agent Loaded ***");
        MyStaticClass.myStaticClass();
    }
    public static boolean isAspectJAgentLoaded() {
        try {
            org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Agent.getInstrumentation();
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError | UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The test class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/application-context.xml"})
public class ProcessorTest { 

    @Test
    public void testProcessorFromContext() {
        if (isAspectJAgentLoaded()) {
            System.out.println("*** AspectJ required agents loaded ***");
        }
        ProcessorRunner.main(new String[]{"myArg"});
    }

    public static boolean isAspectJAgentLoaded() {
        try {
            org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Agent.getInstrumentation();
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError | UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

How come the wished method is well intercepted with the test class while it is not with the main class?

---

**EDIT:** I add the stack traces if it can help.

1) When it is ok by executing the test:

```
objc[73666]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
00:06:25,484 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
00:06:25,484 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback-test.xml] at [file:/Users/richard/dev/spring-by-example/core/aspectj-load-time-weaving/target/test-classes/logback-test.xml]
00:06:25,654 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
00:06:25,935 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
00:06:25,958 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
00:06:26,098 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[CONSOLE] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
00:06:26,098 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[CONSOLE] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
00:06:26,098 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[CONSOLE] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
00:06:26,099 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.springbyexample] to false
00:06:26,099 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.springbyexample level set to DEBUG
00:06:26,100 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[org.springbyexample]
00:06:26,100 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - ROOT level set to INFO
00:06:26,100 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
00:06:26,100 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
00:06:26,102 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@1324409e - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

avr. 24 2017 22:06:26 INFO  org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
avr. 24 2017 22:06:26 INFO  org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
avr. 24 2017 22:06:26 INFO  org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttribute]
avr. 24 2017 22:06:26 INFO  org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttributeSource]
avr. 24 2017 22:06:26 INFO  org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@7d0587f1, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@5d76b067]avr. 24 2017 22:06:26 INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context.xml]
avr. 24 2017 22:06:27 INFO  org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@27808f31: startup date [Tue Apr 25 00:06:27 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
avr. 24 2017 22:06:27 INFO  org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver - Found Spring's JVM agent for instrumentation
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java 5 was not started with preMain -javaagent for AspectJ
avr. 24 2017 22:06:28 INFO  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@59505b48: startup date [Tue Apr 25 00:06:28 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
avr. 24 2017 22:06:28 INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context.xml]
avr. 24 2017 22:06:28 INFO  org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver - Found Spring's JVM agent for instrumentation
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error at org/springbyexample/aspectjLoadTimeWeaving/MyStaticClass.java::0 class {0} is already woven and has not been built in reweavable mode [Xlint:nonReweavableTypeEncountered]
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error at org/springbyexample/aspectjLoadTimeWeaving/PerformanceAdvice.java::0 class {0} is already woven and has not been built in reweavable mode [Xlint:nonReweavableTypeEncountered]
*** hijacked : myStaticClass
ECHO myStaticClass()
avr. 24 2017 22:06:28 INFO  org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@27808f31: startup date [Tue Apr 25 00:06:27 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
avr. 24 2017 22:06:28 INFO  org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver - Removing all registered transformers for class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader

Process finished with exit code 0
```

2) When I execute the main class:

```
objc[73710]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
00:17:44.565 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4563e9ab: startup date [Tue Apr 25 00:17:44 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
00:17:44.656 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:17:44.672 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:17:44.672 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
00:17:44.724 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:17:44.724 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
00:17:44.727 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
00:17:44.735 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context.xml]
00:17:44.763 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
00:17:44.824 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
00:17:44.827 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd}
00:17:44.828 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
00:17:44.882 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.1.xsd
00:17:44.910 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.1.xsd
00:17:44.925 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.x.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Loading bean definitions
00:17:44.936 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.x.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver - Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop=org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache=org.springframework.cache.config.CacheNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/c=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler}
00:17:44.954 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Bean factory for org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4563e9ab: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@34cd072c: defining beans [loadTimeWeaver]; root of factory hierarchy
00:17:44.976 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@8e24743]
00:17:44.978 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@1fc2b765]
00:17:44.981 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@34cd072c: defining beans [loadTimeWeaver]; root of factory hierarchy
00:17:44.982 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'loadTimeWeaver'
00:17:44.982 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'loadTimeWeaver'
00:17:44.995 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'loadTimeWeaver' to allow for resolving potential circular references
00:17:44.996 [main] INFO  o.s.c.w.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver - Found Spring's JVM agent for instrumentation
00:17:44.997 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'loadTimeWeaver'
00:17:44.998 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@587c290d]
00:17:44.999 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
00:17:45.000 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
00:17:45.000 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
00:17:45.001 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
*** AspectJ Agent Loaded ***
ECHO myStaticClass()

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [aspectj-load-time-weaving example](https://github.com/spring-by-example/spring-by-example/tree/master/core/aspectj-load-time-weaving), the `META-INF/aop.xml` file is only present in the `src/tests/resources` folder. That's why the weaving works only when we execute the test.

To make it work also when we run directly the main method, we need to add `META-INF/aop.xml` in the `src/java/resources` folder.