# How to manipulate a class' bytecode just before it is loaded?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, javaagents, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to find a way to manipulate the bytecode of a class (at runtime) just before it is loaded. I need to do this because the manipulation depends on something that is not present before `main` (and potentially before the subject class is loaded).

I already looked at java agents. The `premain` method is obviously not applicable here, because it is executed before `main`, which means it can't depend on something that is set up in `main`.
The other option seems to be `agentmain` and [manually loading the agent at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26662586/9687309). Now the problem with this is that in the newer versions (9+), the dependencies needed to do that (tools.jar) don't seem to be present anymore.

Now, I'd like to know what would be the best way to manipulate bytecode at a specific point in runtime or just before a class is loaded and if that is still possible somehow with Java 9+.

Comment: I think the tools are "present" but not present by default.  They changed the way Java JDK is distributed after Java 8 due to the new release schedule.  Not sure where they went, ask around and I'm sure you can find them.

Comment: In `premain` you just adding transformer, it won't be used right away. It will be used later on just before class will be loaded - check https://jrebel.com/rebellabs/how-to-inspect-classes-in-your-jvm/ and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `premain` method is obviously not applicable here, because it is
>   executed before `main`, which means it can't depend on something that is
>   set up in `main`

This is not true. The agent does not need to modify the class bytecode right at the agent load time. It may just register [`ClassFileTransformer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#addTransformer(java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer)) and postpone bytecode manipulation until the target class is loaded later. Alternatively an agent can simply save `Instrumentation` instance to be used later at any convenient moment of time.

> in the newer versions (9+), the dependencies needed to do that
>   (tools.jar) don't seem to be present anymore

This is also not quite correct. Attach API exists in all new versions of JDK. Since JDK 9 it no longer requires `tools.jar`, instead it belongs to [`jdk.attach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.attach/com/sun/tools/attach/package-summary.html) module.

To facilitate attach in runtime you may use [`byte-buddy-agent`](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/tree/master/byte-buddy-agent) or a standalone [`jattach`](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) utility. Both work with JDK 8- as well as with JDK 9+.